# Convert a TXT delimited TAB to Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking for a mean to convert my TXT file into a Google Sheets :

[image: Extract of my TXT FILE]

```
function convert_txt_gsheets(){
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName('file.txt').next();
  var body = file.getBlob().getDataAsString().split(/\n/);
  var result = body.map( r => r.split(/\t/));
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0].getRange(1,1,result.length,result[0].length).setValues(result);
return;
}
```

An error occured "The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 1 but the range has 18."

Does someone have an idea ?

If I import the txt file manually it works but I need to do it through an G apps script.

Comment: Can you try specifying the directory or specify the actual ID of the file? you might be getting the other `file.txt` if there is something other than that file with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

I only see typos/wrong method names for `getBlob` and `getFilesByName` (you used `getBlobl` and `getFileByName`), but aside from that, the only possible issue that will cause this is that something from the file is written unexpectedly.

#### Update:

- Upon checking, your txt file has a line at the bottom containing a blank row. Delete that and you should successfully write the file. That's why the error is range is expecting 18 columns but that last row only has 1 due to not having any data.
- You could also filter the file before writing. Removing rows that doesn't have 18 columns will fix the issue. See code below:

#### Modification:

```
var result = body.map( r => r.split(/\t/)).filter( r => r.length == 18);
```

#### Successful run:

[image: modify]

[image: output]

Comment: Hey, there is my txt file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a4xcluRPJqt6fmnhmv0a8B7WBIJb6ZPf/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I have updated my answer @BigBenne. It seems your file has an extra row at the end containing no data. Make sure to remove them before processing the file.

Comment: @BigBenne, I updated the answer to include a script solution that will exclude/remove the rows that doesn't have the expected number of columns.

If this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Did the filter work @BigBenne?

Comment: Alright thanks a lot !!!!